# regex exact matching

Tags: regex

how do i ensure my regex to match exactly.

I currently have a string that something like this

```
"heeeeehaaaaaleeee"
```

My regex is `"[hee]"`

It now shows up that it matches all the characters (h/e). I want it to match only `"hee"` in the string and not `h or e`.

Comment: `"hee"` is a valid regex you can use to match that string

Comment: `str.startsWith("hee")`?

Comment: I'm assuming the actual use case is more complex, and this is a simplified example (hence interest in regexes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're overthinking it. `[hee]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), and is actually equivalent to `[he]`. Both of these will match precisely one instance of either the characters `h` or `e`. If you want to match the literal string `hee`, that's the regex you need. Something like (translate to your language of choice):

```
targetString.match(/hee/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the string "hee" instead to match the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Try regex match for "hee" instead of [hee].